# I'm on a vortex android 13 phone and the developer app disappeared on me. How do I get it back

Tags: applications

I'm on a vortex android 13 phone and I just got the developer installed and I'm not sure what happened but all of a sudden the developer disappeared and when I went to install it again it won't let me. I tap on on the right area and nothing happens now. Nothing at all happens when I tap the build number.i need help to find it and to get it back without doing a factory reset because I have a lot of data on my phone that I really want to keep. Help me someone please.

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. By "vortex android 13 phone", did you mean [Vortex Cellular](https://vortexcellular.com/devices)? That said, developer options are not usually "installed", but only "enabled" by tapping the build number 7 times. Could you explain how did you install it before?